# “Invalid column name” error in SQL Server 2014 when creating a merge procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a `merge` procedure using multiple columns. However, I'm also getting multiple errors about column names.

[image]

I would appreciate pointers on where I'm going wrong.

---

```
create PROCEDURE [Etl].[MergeRPIData2] AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

MERGE [RetailPrice].[RetailPriceIndex] AS Trgt
USING (SELECT ItemId, Outlet, DataYear, DataMonth
    FROM [RetailPrice].[StagingRPI]) AS Src (ItemId, Outlet, DataYear, DataMonth)
    ON Trgt.ItemId=Src.ItemId AND Trgt.Outlet=Src.Outlet AND Trgt.DataYear=Src.DataYear AND Trgt.DataMonth=Src.DataMonth

WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET ID=Src.ID, ItemId=Src.ItemId, Item=Src.Item, RPIType=Src.RPIType, Outlet=Src.Outlet, RPIWeight=Src.RPIWeight, PrevMonth=Src.PrevMonth, 
            CurrMonth=Src.CurrMonth, Remarks=Src.Remarks, DataYear=Src.DataYear, DataMonth=Src.DataMonth

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (ID, ItemId, Item, RPIType, Outlet, RPIWeight, PrevMonth, CurrMonth, Remarks, DataYear, DataMonth)
    VALUES (Src.[ID], Src.[ItemId], Src.[Item], Src.[RPIType], Src.[Outlet], Src.[RPIWeight], Src.[PrevMonth], Src.[CurrMonth], Src.[Remarks], Src.[DataYear], Src.[DataMonth])

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
    DELETE;

DELETE FROM [RetailPrice].[StagingRPI]
```

Comment: `USING RetailPrice.StagingRPI AS Src ON ...` You return only 4 columns from SRC and use columns that are not listed in `SELECT`

Comment: Why would you take a pic of your code instead of copy/paste it?

Comment: Can you please post your query as text directly in your question ? Pictures are not easy to read... Thanks !

Comment: No one is going to read that tiny letters.  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: red squiggly lines are not errors.   If you get an actual error message when you execute this code, then post the error.

Comment: The error messages are...

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MergeRPIData2, Line 19
Invalid column name 'CurrMonth'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MergeRPIData2, Line 15
Invalid column name 'CurrMonth'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MergeRPIData2, Line 19
Invalid column name 'RPIType'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MergeRPIData2, Line 14
Invalid column name 'RPIType'.
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading SQL on a picture is not easy... However one thing that stroke my eye is that your `WHEN MATCHED` and `WHEN ǸOT MATCHED` clauses refer to many columns in `Src` that are not actually returned by the `Src` subquery.

Namely, `Src` returns 4 columns :

- ItemId
- Outlet
- DateYear
- DataMonth

Meanwhile, the `WHEN (NOT) MATCH` clauses refer to following fields (missing fields are indicated as **bold**) :

- **ID**
- ItemId
- **Item**
- **RPIType**
- Outlet
- **RPIWeight**
- **PrevMonth**
- **CurMonth**
- **Remarks**
- DataYear
- DataMonth

I imagine that all missing fields are actually available in the `[RetailPrice].[StagingRPI]` tables, that `Src` is based upon (if not, you have a serious design problem).

To solve the multiple *Invalid column name* errors that the query is generating, you need to adapt the `Src` subquery so it returns all needed fields. I could not generate the correct query for you as you did not post the original query as text.

Comment: I edited the SELECT statement as recommended and the code now executes without errors.

`MERGE [RetailPrice].[RetailPriceIndex] AS Trgt
USING (SELECT ItemId, Item, RPIType, Outlet, RPIWeight, PrevMonth, CurrMonth, Remarks, DataYear, DataMonth
 FROM [RetailPrice].[StagingRPI]) AS Src (ItemId, Item, RPIType, Outlet, RPIWeight, PrevMonth, CurrMonth, Remarks, DataYear, DataMonth)
    ON Trgt.ItemId=Src.ItemId AND Trgt.Outlet=Src.Outlet AND Trgt.DataYear=Src.DataYear AND Trgt.DataMonth=Src.DataMonth`

Comment: However, I'm trying to add data from an Excel sheet to SQL, but  when I run the VBA I get a run-time error about "A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows." More research...

Comment: Try to add a `DISTINCT` in your `SELECT`, like `... AS Trgt USING (SELECT DISTINCT ItemId, Item, RPIType, ...`

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` did not help. I got the same error.